# Django query for the below scenerio to get count

Tags: django, postgresql

Table1 :

```
    **name     status**
    shankar    Good
     vimal      Bad
     Sekar      Good
    Shankar    Good
    Shankar    Good
```

I would like to get count like this

```
Good 2
Bad  1
```

Anyone help me find django query for the above scenerio

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model is called User, you can use values and annotate methods from the Django ORM like this

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.values(
     ‘status’).annotate(
          count=Count(‘name’, distinct=True))
```

Comment: The thing you said will give the result value of Good =4 and Bad =1. that's not correct for my question